# Windows 10 sidebar like action center

Tags: c#, windows

I'm wondering if there is any official .NET (C#) way\API to create a slide-out sidebar window for my app like the windows 10 action center or the wireless network list.

Comment: Use the `SHAppBarMessage` function to register an auto-hide appbar.

Comment: An answer from @RaymondChen himself! Many thanks :)